# Swift: UIButton un-clickable overlapping views

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

when I'm unwinding a segue by clicking on a button with a cross image which is **1/4th inside a UIView** and **3/4th outside the UIView** now when I press on button the part which is inside the UIView then unwind segue works but if I click outside of UIView then it does not works.

[image: Click here for Image]

As you can see from above image if I click inside the blue line then other view controller opens and If I click outside blue line of cross button the unwinding of segue does't work, why?

**You can View the Video**

```html
<a href="https://imgflip.com/gif/24bh0k"><img src="https://i.imgflip.com/24bh0k.gif" title="made at imgflip.com"/></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross button seems to be inside the card view rather than superview. Put the button inside superview, over the card view but outside the card view.

Do something like this
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

take the button up on the view and set its constraints properly . May be your problem will resolved.